# Android keeping all layout elements on the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I have a fragment inside a RelativeLayout. This fragment contains a ListView and a Button and is loaded and shown below another layout. The fragment is not always visible and the data in the ListView changes each time it is shown.

Everything works well except for one thing. If the screen space is too small, the ListView height shrinks (correct) but the Button wont be shown. It is just chopped off. I have a border around the entire fragment Layout that shows properly all the time but if there isn't enough room, the button just vanishes and the border shows around the ListView correctly.

How can I keep my Button on the screen as well and just shrink the ListView? My fragment layout is:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/quickFilterLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#66000000">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/quickFilterArrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/quick_filter_top_arrow"
        android:contentDescription="quick filter up arrow" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/quickFilterMainContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/quickFilterArrow"
        android:background="@drawable/quick_filters_background" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/quickFilterListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="#C8C7CC"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/closeQuickFilterButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/quickFilterListView"
            android:background="@drawable/quick_filter_close_button_selector"
            android:text="Close" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Would be better to assign weights to your layouts.

Comment: ListViews just don't understand wrap_content, always fill up the entire screen, try adding layout_above=@+id/closeQuickFilterButton in ListView. Also, remove layout_below="@id/quickFilterListView" to avoid circular dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This makes it such that your button occupies the 40dp while the listview takes up everything else.